# Free implementation of “bounded priority queue” in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I was searching for a free implementation of a "bounded" priority queue.  The algorithm has been discussed many times on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329312/free-implementation-of-bounded-priority-queue-in-c).  I took a shot and wrote a STL-like bounded_priority_queue class (which implements the most efficient algorithm using a priority_queue with a "flipped" compare as the underlying container).

I do have some questions:

1. Any comments on my interface?  I couldn't think of anything more fine-grained than `pop_all()`.  I provided a constructor that takes in an iterator range, since `std::partial_sort` can only be called using random access iterators.
2. Any comments on my implementation?  I tried to mimic the style of the STL that comes with MSVC.  (It's not my natural style.)
3. Is `flipped_compare` part of the STL?  It feels like it should be there somewhere.
4. Is there any way to more succinctly implement the dispatch for bidir & random_access iterators?  I couldn't come up with any way without explicit defining partial specializations of `_pop_all()` for both iterator categories.
5. Any reason why `std::priority_queue` defines the `_Container` template parameter before the `_Pr` template parameter?  As a user, I would probably want specialize `_Pr` more frequently than `_Container`.  (I kept the same order, but I don't like it.)

Here's the code (feel free to copy):

```
#include <queue>
#include <iterator>

template < typename _Ty, typename _Pr = std::less<_Ty> >
struct flipped_compare {
    flipped_compare() : comp() {}
    explicit flipped_compare(const _Pr& _Pred) : comp(_Pred) {}
    bool operator()(const _Ty& l, const _Ty& r) { return comp(r,l); }
    _Pr comp;
};


template < typename _Ty, typename _Container = std::vector<_Ty>,
    typename _Pr = std::less<_Ty> >
class bounded_priority_queue
{
public:
    typedef _Ty value_type;
    typedef typename _Container::size_type size_type;

    explicit bounded_priority_queue(size_type _Max_size)
        : max_sz(_Max_size) {}

    bounded_priority_queue(size_type _Max_size, const _Pr& _Pred)
        : c( flipped_compare<_Ty,_Pr>(_Pred) ), max_sz(_Max_size) {}

    template <typename _InIt>
    bounded_priority_queue(size_type _Max_size, _InIt _First, _InIt _Last)
        : max_sz(_Max_size)
        {
            for (; _First != _Last; ++_First) push( *_First );
        }

    template <typename _InIt>
    bounded_priority_queue(size_type _Max_size, _InIt _First,
        _InIt _Last, _Pr _Pred)
        : c( flipped_compare<_Ty,_Pr>(_Pred) ), max_sz(_Max_size)
        {
            for (; _First != _Last; ++_First) push( *_First );
        }

    size_type max_size() const { return max_sz; }

    size_type size() const { return c.size(); }

    void push(const value_type& _Val)
        {
        if ( size() < max_size() ) c.push(_Val);
        else if ( comp(c.top(), _Val) ) { c.pop(); c.push(_Val); }
        }

    template <typename _OutIt>
    void pop_all(_OutIt _Dest)
        {
        _pop_all( _Dest,
            typename std::iterator_traits<_OutIt>::iterator_category() );
        }

private:
    template <typename _OutIt, typename _Tag>
    void _pop_all(_OutIt _Dest, _Tag)
        {
        std::vector<_Ty> tmp( size() );
        _pop_all2( tmp.begin() );
        std::copy( tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), _Dest );
        }

    template <typename _OutIt>
    void _pop_all(_OutIt _Dest, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag)
        {
        _pop_all2( _Dest );
        }

    template <typename _OutIt>
    void _pop_all(_OutIt _Dest, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
        {
        _pop_all2( _Dest );
        }

    template <typename _BidIt>
    void _pop_all2(_BidIt _Dest)
        {
        _BidIt _First = _Dest;
        while ( !c.empty() ) {
            *_Dest++ = c.top();
            c.pop();
        }
        std::reverse( _First, _Dest );
        }


    std::priority_queue< _Ty, _Container, flipped_compare<_Ty, _Pr> > c;
    _Pr comp;
    size_type max_sz;
};

#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int K = 20, N = 500;
    std::list<int> l;
    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter(l), N, &std::rand );
    bounded_priority_queue<int> q( K, l.begin(), l.end() );
    q.pop_all( std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: flipped_compare is actually called `std::more`.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: What is `std::more`? Do you have a reference because I can't find it.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I think he is talking about [std::greater](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater).

Comment: oops, that's embarrassing. I was so sure because I happened to use it before, and I was so wrong telling std::more. :( It is std::greater. Sorry

Comment: why do you need flipped_compare, shouldn't it be just std::less for a priority queue , which has the maximum element as top() ? and
is pop(),push()  if the element to insert is smaller < top(), the most efficient way?, can that not be combined somehow?

Comment: Why not add -> begin() and end()  for the container, to be able to iterate over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the **implementation**.  You **may not use them**.  Ever.

You might also want to specify whether you're interested in all advice, or only that relevant to C++03; I don't see much C++11 could do here, but it's generally an important distinction.

Now, comments:

- Why not have `flipped_compare::operator()` be `const`?  Not very significant, but looks like it'd work.
- I suggest using `std::less<typename _Container::value_type>` as your default `_Pr`, as that's what `std::priority_queue` does.
- The constructors should probably be implemented in terms of `std::for_each` or somesuch.
- Your indentation is inconsistent.
- Swap is a fairly important omission, in my opinion.